# Displaying my console.log on the screen

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript that prints out all prime numbers 1 - 100, and I am using innerHTML to printout the results. My console is giving me the list of numbers but the innerHTML is giving me a single number. 100 I think. How can I display the list of numbers same way I am printing in my console but inside a div of ID="prime"?

Here is what I wrote

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
   var invalid = false;

   for (var j = 2; j <= i; j++) {

       if (i % j===0 && j !== i) {
           invalid = true;
       }
   }

   if (invalid === false) {
       console.log(i);
   }
}
document.getElementById('prime').innerHTML = i;
```

My Div

```
<div id="prime"> </div>
```

My Console ouputs 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...97 but my div outputs 101

Here is a [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/qqbjGy)

thanks

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself, not a third-party site. It's really quite easy with the Stack Snippets feature...

Comment: `My Console ouputs 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...97 but my div outputs 101` - because that's exactly what you coded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your placement of the code is wrong. For starters, put it like so:

```
 if (invalid === false) {
    console.log(i);
    document.getElementById('prime').innerHTML = i;
}
```

Also, if you use that code, it'll only display the **last** value of `i`. To fix that, use `+=` instead of `=`

```
if (invalid === false) {
    console.log(i);
    document.getElementById('prime').innerHTML += i + " | ";
}
```

Finally, I'd add a line (" | ") behind the `i`, to make the number sepetations clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('prime').innerHTML += i;
```

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
   var invalid = false;

   for (var j = 2; j <= i; j++) {

       if (i % j===0 && j !== i) {
           invalid = true;
       }
   }

   if (invalid === false) {
       console.log(i);
       document.getElementById('prime').innerHTML += "<br />" + i;
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="prime"></div>
```

You need to add to the already existing HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You should update innerHTML at each step in the loop rather than only at the end. You should also append each new number to the existing content rather than overriding it:

```
document.getElementById('prime').innerHTML += ' ' + i;
```

Answer (score 1):

For an output **horizontally**, put all in a **string** with `result += i + " "` and assign it to the `<div>`.

```js
var prime = document.getElementById("prime"),
  result = ""; // Result is a string

for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  var invalid = false;

  for (var j = 2; j <= i; j++) {

    if (i % j === 0 && j !== i) {
      invalid = true;
    }
  }

  if (invalid === false) {
    result += i + " ";
    console.log(i);
  }
}

prime.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="prime"></div>
```